# Clustering using the pam algorithm in R

Tags: r, clustering

I´m using the `pam()` R function to perform clustering. As far as I know, the `pamk()` function serves as a wrapper to `pam()`, and evaluates the optimal number of clusters. However, using the same data and parameters I get different results.

For example, calling `pamk()` and `pam()` as follows returns 2 clusters with different medoids values:

```
pk <- pamk(dist, krange=2:10, criterion="ch", usepam=TRUE, diss=TRUE)

pk.2 <- pam(dist,2,diss=TRUE)
```

How can it be?

Thank you,
Anat

Answer (score 4):

First off, if you are using functions from a package, please mention it in your question (in this case, `pamk`is in package `fpc`). It will make it easier for people to help you.

Second, it also helps if you provide a reproducible example (that is, give us the data, or part of it, that gives you your problem).

Now, as to your problem. If you list the source of `pamk`, (you do this by typing the name of the function, without brackets, in the R prompt, and pressing enter), you'll see that indeed it runs `pam` for your set of `k` values, and then picks the best one based on your criterion of choice.

What it *doesn't* do, however, is run the algorithm several times for the same `k` and check the stability of the medioids: the `pam` algorithm is not completely deterministic, and can depend on the initial (typically randomly determined) starting points. In fact, if you run `pam` several times on your data, with the same `k`, I would expect (in your case) to see different results as well!

Normally, this is an indication that the clusters are not well defined in your data (or at least not in a form that can be picked up by `pam`). It is likely that, if you were to include 1 in your `krange`, this would give the best result: the best 'partitioning' is *no* partitioning.

**Conclusion**: if you get this type of result from `pam`, don't trust it!

Disclaimer: since I cannot see your data, and you don't mention how the 2 results are different, I'm sort of guessing what the problem is, here. If your problem is really that the return value of `pamk` is a list, of which the item `pamobject` is really the `pam` object (imagine that), the above is still true but less relevant to you (for now).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reponse.
The data may be found here http://www.mediafire.com/?n833zkcbtrdz3t5so.
My first guess was also that the different results were due to the random property of the algorithm.
But unlike what you described, I don´t get different results in every run. When running pam() with k=2 I get that the medoids are 68 and 147, and when running pamk() I get that the medoids are 73 and 142 (the optimal number of clusters was 2). The different medoids result in different clustering of course.
This is strange, I went through pamk() source code and it simply calls pam()!

Comment: http://uploading.com/files/am96bm87/dist.RData/

Comment: Sorry, I think this link would work:  [link](http://uploading.com/files/am96bm87/dist.RData/)

Comment: You could create a new function custompamk, give it the same source as pamk and add some logging (e.g. `cat` statements) to check where the difference occurs. Check whether it differs immediately after the `pam` call (with k=2). If it does: check the parameters passed to `pam` then: there must be some subtle difference (e.g. handling of `NA`s or similar)